# What is this connector part called and where can I buy one?

Tags: metal, aluminum, connectors

I am trying to find a replacement for this connecting part on a ballet barre. It's kind of like a long tee clamp but internal. The poles it connects to are aluminium. Essentially 2 of the key locking mechanisms have jammed so I can't tighten them and I've bent 2 allen keys trying to lock them. Thanks in advance!
[image: picture of part]

Comment: Are you certain that it's internal? Have you been able to disassemble any other joint? Is it possible that you're seeing a connection of internal joints that are sleeved by the outer tubing? Unless the joints are extremely tightly compressed, you might be able to rotate the outer sleeves between joints if the tape is removed.

Comment: please remove the Tee from the pipes and post pictures of it

Comment: One sometimes sees connectors like this on chain link fences, although the poles on those are galvanized steel rather than aluminum. If you have a nearby fence company, remove it and ask them if they have one that would work.

Comment: It is definitely internal as I have taken it off previously. But for some reason the allen key mechanisms are jamming open. So it's not that it's stuck on but trying to constantly fall off. Hence the tape to hold it in place for the moment. My wife has finally heard back from the manufacturer so will see if we can order direct, if not I'll take it apart and post pics. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried backing them out and rotating the pipe so there is new place for the Allen set screws to contact. Have you taken it all apart and inspected the threads and set screws and pipes ?

Comment: I was actually trying to get the second one of the set screws out to see why the first one may have jammed when it jammed too. So I'm hesitant to take the third one out to check!

Answer (score 1):

As a generic term, those are called "structural pipe fittings" and that is a "Tee". As to the specific brand and type with the internal connections, that's likely something proprietary to that supplier, most likely because it is being used for ballet, so they wouldn't want things protruding that could cause injuries.

Comment: Ok great thanks. I'll keep trying with the supplier then. If I have no luck at least I know what term to search for!